# Can't use find with more -name parameters linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to find *.cpp , *.c and *.h files with the time when was last modified and the size in bytes, but the following command doesn't show anything...

```
find . -name \*.c\* -o -name \*.h -printf "%s %p %t\n"
```

Why doesn't show anything?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programing code. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parentheses.

```
find . \( -name \*.c\* -o -name \*.h \) -printf "%s %p %t\n"
```

Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find